# MySQL how do you truncate a table in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, truncate

I have a stored procedure that writes results to a Result table. How do you truncate / erase a table from within a stored procedure?

example

```
call peformTest()

truncate TestResultTable;

//do stuff with new data to insert into TestResultTable
end
```

Comment: Note to anyone reading this: 'TRUNCATE' cannot be called before DECLARE. That was my problem

Comment: In my case, I had written `TRUMCATE`, and after staring at it for 30 minutes, after reading your answer, I finally spotted the typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove all data from the table, then your syntax is correct:

```
truncate testResultTable;
```

or

```
truncate table testResultTable;
```

Depending on your specific needs, if you need to get rid of the table correctly and then re-create it, you can do:

```
drop table testResultTable;
create table testResultTable as select ... from ... where ...
```

Comment: Note to anyone reading this: 'TRUNCATE' cannot be called before DECLARE. That was my problem

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is any difference in SQL vs stored procedure in the way they execute. But usually the format for truncating is: `Truncate Table tableName;` here is the reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure simple:

DELETE FROM table WHERE 1 = 1

---

Other example in PL/SQL:

[PL/SQL SP Truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625743/truncating-a-table-in-a-stored-procedure)

---

Or solution by @Churk.

Comment: That is an Oracle solution, not a MySQL solution.