# How to combine 8 queries into one to create a procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, procedure

I have a table I created to match an online Template for uploading inventory to Amazon. In total, it has 440 columns. I'm not worried about that, and neither are they, it is mostly necessary. It pulls from two other tables that I'll call table1 and table2. I'll call the other one templateTable.

Basically, I'm starting with a TRUNCATE to completely wipe the information on the templateTable. I want it empty when it gets filled, for no reason other than it makes me feel comfortable. No other table gets truncated, just this table every time the query is run.

After that, there is a massive INSERT query that takes info from table1 and table2 and puts all of that into templateTable's specific columns.

Query 3 is an update at this point, and so is pretty much queries 3 - 8. They're all update queries. I did them separately from the second query, where everything gets populated, because each update has a CASE and different requirements.

I wanted to create a procedure for these queries so they could just run the one procedure and call it a day. But I'm uncertain how to combine the 8 queries that fill and correct the information in this templateTable. I should mention I'm not just taking info from one table and sticking it in the templateTable- it is more like "case when table1.modelNum = 1234 then templateTable.modelNum = 5678".

Comment: Which statement does trouble you? Is it `UPDATE`? You can only update a single table -- not multiple, as your example shows.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Are you asking how to create a stored procedure?  It would help if you would end your post with a specific question. You tagged with sql-server, but in your question you reference MySQL.  Which one are you using?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll try to explain better- the Updates work all right, but that's because they're separated. When you include several tables after UPDATE it's because you have to include which tables you're including from. Trust me, that part works.

Apologies for the mis-tag; this is my first time posting a question. I'll fix that. It's MySQL.

Basically... I have 8 queries. My workplace is not very good with programming though, and editing the query or even running it is a bit too off-putting for most everyone here. I wanted to combine the 8 queries into one. Let me re-write my question

Comment: All right, I edited the question @BrianPressler. Hopefully it makes better sense now. It's too vague for me to try to make some fake version of the queries, but I can try if you need me to. It'll just be long-winded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all of your 8 SQL statements inside of a procedure in MySQL like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure()
BEGIN 
    <SQL STATEMENT 1>;
    <SQL STATEMENT 2>;
    <SQL STATEMENT 3>;
    <SQL STATEMENT ...>;
END//
```

Then to call it you submit:

```
exec MyProcedure;
```

Comment: That looks amazing! Let me give this a try!

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seem to like the truncate as the first query in there.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Make sure you call TRUNCATE before DECLARE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470398/mysql-how-do-you-truncate-a-table-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Sorry for not responding- I did get it to work. I wasn't at work yesterday to come back to stack. Thank very very very much!