# plSQL Syntax For Writing Stored Procedure w/ 3 Variables

Tags: oracle, plsql, coldfusion

I have this long block of SQL statements I need to make a stored procedure for that accept 3 variables. The variables are invoice, NewDate, TransactionDate and the datatypes are integer, date, and date respectively. I've tried to create the stored procedure, but the syntax is messing me up. I'll be calling the stored procedure using Coldfusion and cfstoredproc, hence the pound signs. Not that I need any help with the ColdFusion. Just trying to provide as much info as possible.

```
truncate table fix_the_date; commit; 
insert into fix_the_date 
(Location,Invoice,NewDate,TransactionDate) 
values 
('Corporate', '#invoice#'
, to_date('#NewDate#', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
,to_date('#TransactionDate#','mm/dd/yyyy')); 
commit;
<!--- About a dozen other queries go here that I won't waste your time with--->
```

**Update 1:**
Below is what I have for the Stored Procedure as of now. I'm getting the following error:

> Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC
>   Driver][Oracle]ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a
>   numeric was expected ORA-06512: at "THEDB.FIXMISSINGDATE", line 13
>   ORA-06512: at line 1 The error occurred on line 4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE THEDB."FIXMISSINGDATE" (Invoice integer, NewTransactionDate date, TransactionDate date) IS
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE FixTheDate;
commit;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE DeletePayTrans';
commit;

insert into FixTheDate(Site, Invoice_No, Pay_Date, Old_Date)
values ('Corporate', 'TO_CHAR(#Invoice#)','#NewTransactionDate#','#TransactionDate#');
commit;

/*******************************
Plus a bunch of other queries here
*******************************/

END FIXMISSINGDATE;
/
```

**Update 2:** Per feedback in comments, removed pound signs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE THEDB."FIXMISSINGDATE" (Invoice integer, NewTransactionDate date, TransactionDate date) IS
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE FixTheDate;
commit;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE DeletePayTrans';
commit;

insert into FixTheDate(Site, Invoice_No, Pay_Date, Old_Date)
values ('Corporate', TO_CHAR(Invoice), NewTransactionDate, TransactionDate);
commit;

/*******************************
Plus a bunch of other queries here
*******************************/

END FIXMISSINGDATE;
/
```

Comment: Your datatypes can't be dates if you're converting them to dates with the `to_date` function.

Comment: In Oracle, `truncate table`, and all DDL, performs an implicit commit at the beginning and end of execution. So the first commit is redundant.

Comment: The last commit is also unnecessary when connecting from ColdFusion.  Also, pass date or timestamp objects from ColdFusion to your SP.  Don't muck about with strings.

Comment: The question is how to put it all together in a stored procedure.

Comment: @FSUKXAZ - Can you please update your question with what you have tried, in terms of a stored procedure, and any error messages.

Comment: Question updated.  Thank you.

Comment: The error: Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected ORA-06512: at "THEDB.FIXMISSINGDATE", line 13 ORA-06512: at line 1 
The error occurred on line 4.

Comment: The new error: Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00905: object THEDB.FIXMISSINGDATE is invalid ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: *Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]...PLS-00905: object THEDB.FIXMISSINGDATE is invalid* Remove CF from the equation (temporarily).  Get it running in Oracle first.

Comment: Also, not sure if it is a copy+paste error, but you are missing a closing quote at the end of one of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statements.

Comment: Hi all.  I was getting a syntax error further down in the stored procedure (one of those additional queries) which I corrected.  It now runs as expected. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue probably relates to trying to issue DDL statements in a stored procedure (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625743/truncating-a-table-in-a-stored-procedure)).

I'm going to assume that your `NewDate` and `TransactionDate` are also varchar2 (since your insert statement won't work if they're actually dates).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc(
    invoice         IN integer,
    NewDate         IN varchar2,
    TransactionDate IN varchar2) AS

BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE fix_the_date';

    INSERT INTO fix_the_date (Location,Invoice,NewDate,TransactionDate) 
    VALUES ('Corporate', invoice, TO_DATE(NewDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy'),
    TO_DATE(TransactionDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')); 
    COMMIT;

END;
/
```

...or if you really are passing dates:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc(
    invoice         IN integer,
    NewDate         IN date,
    TransactionDate IN date) AS

BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE fix_the_date';

    INSERT INTO fix_the_date (Location,Invoice,NewDate,TransactionDate) 
    VALUES ('Corporate', invoice, NewDate, TransactionDate); 
    COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Comment: Yes, both are dates.  What is gob?  Also, I just noticed that the variable "Invoice" is coming in as an integer from one table and the table its getting inserted into its a varchar2.  So should I change the stored proc to show invoice as varchar2?   I went ahead and built the stored procedure and now am getting error trying to execute it.

Comment: Haha...sorry, I was testing on a made-up table - fixed name.  You can just cast the invoice to a varchar2 when you insert it.  Leave it as `integer` in parameter, but insert as: `TO_CHAR(invoice)`

Comment: I updated the question with what code I have for the Stored Procedure as of now.  I'm getting the following error:  Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected ORA-06512: at "THEDB.FIXMISSINGDATE", line 13 ORA-06512: at line 1 The error occurred on line 4

Comment: Remove the `#` signs, and the single quotes around your parameters.  Use the example I've given - don't add extra improvisations where unnecessary.

Comment: How will it know its a ColdFusion variable without them?  This stored procedure is being called in a CFM page where those variables exist.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ColdFusion; but stored procedures are *stored* (as the name implies) in the database.  The parameter names you give your (database) stored procedure are internal to the database, and are unrelated to whatever you name variables in ColdFusion. When you call the store procedure, it is likely passing parameters by position - the names are irrelevant (only number of parameters and datatype).  So call your ColdFusion variables what you want, but don't mangle the variable names in the database stored procedure.

Comment: [from here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/beg_storedproc.html), `...Note that in ColdFusion, passed inputs to stored procedures are based on a matched position, not by "name" attribute values.`

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll remove the quotes and pound signs, and play with it some more.

Comment: *How will it know its a ColdFusion variable without them?* It won't. The database doesn't (and shouldn't) know anything about CF.  Any CF variables will be evaluated by the CF server *before* the stored procedure is executed. All that gets sent to Oracle is pure SQL (and literal values).  *Re: passed inputs to stored procedures* IIRC, there were some changes to that in CF10 or 11. However, as Gerrat said, it is hard to go wrong with positional notation.

Comment: Here is the CF if that helps: <cfstoredproc procedure="FixMissingDate" datasource="#application.datasourcename#">
 <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Invoice#"> 
 <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#NewTransactionDate#">
 <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#TransactionDate#"> 
</cfstoredproc>

Comment: The error I'm getting now: Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00905: object CWSADM.FIXMISSINGDATE is invalid ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
The error occurred on line 5.

Comment: @FSUKXAZ - Thanks for posting more details, but ...  **please post code and error messages in the question itself, NOT the comments section** :) Aside from being hard to read and easily overlooked, comments are temporary and may be deleted at any time.

Comment: Hi all.  I was getting a syntax error further down in the stored procedure (one of those additional queries) which I corrected.  It now runs as expected. Thank you all for your help!